# Stack Frame not correct with GCC and STM32

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, stm32, system-calls

I am trying to create simple SVC Handler in GNU GCC (Not ARM GCC). If SVC service is called, it enters `SVC_Handler()` correctly, but when I try to find the SVC number used to call SVC Handler (`svc_number`), I get value 248 instead of 1.

I'm using CubeMX IDE and Nucleo-F401RE board.

Code:

```
void SVC_Handler(void)
{
     asm volatile (
            "TST lr, #4\t\n"
            "ITE EQ\t\n"
            "MRSEQ r0, msp\t\n"
            "MRSNE r0, psp\t\n"
            "B %[SVC_Handler_Main]\t\n"
            :
            : [SVC_Handler_Main] "i" (SVC_Handler_Main)
            : "r0"
    );

}

void SVC_Handler_Main(unsigned int* svc_args) {
     uint8_t svc_number;

     svc_number = ((char* )svc_args[6])[-2];
     switch(svc_number) { // <- that's where I get 248 instead of 1
     case SVC_ADD:
         SVC_Add_Handler(svc_args[0], svc_args[1]);
         break;
     default:
         break;
     }
}

int __attribute__ ((noinline)) SVC_Service_Add(int x, int y) {
    svc(SVC_ADD);
}

#define SVC_ADD 1

#define svc(code) asm volatile ("SVC %[immediate]"::[immediate] "I" (code))
```

I used watch expression with breakpoint after `svc_number` and it's value is 248, instead of 1 that it should be.

Service Calls (SVC) are used mainly in RTOS design for software to enter privileged mode. ARM GCC has some nice support for SV calls, whereas in GNU GCC you have to do it all yourself. The theory goes like this:
When a SV call (in my case SVC_Service_Add() ) is made, it invokes the SVC_Handler(). SVC_Handler() checks which stack is used (main msp or process psp), that information is found by reading bit 2 of Link Register (LR). Depending on that, either msp or psp is saved in r0. After that, compiler puts r0,r1,r2,r3,r12,r14, return address and xPSR in svc_args, so those parameters can be used in `SVC_Handler_Main`. `svc_args[0]=r0`, `svc_args[1]=r1`,...,`svc_args[6]=SP` (the one we are interested in, the one where SVC number is kept).

Since Cortex M4 stack is full descending, we need to do [-2] to get the byte of svc_args[6] we are interested in. Since the call to the SVC_Handler was done by the `SVC_ADD macro (0x01)`, `((char *) svc_args[6])[-2]` should equal to SVC_ADD, so a proper function can be called from SVC_Handler_Main(). I'm not getting 1, I'm getting 248 for some reason.

**Question**: why is `svc_number` equal to **248** whereas I was expecting **1**

Comment: providing negative integers as arguments of arrays is not recommended. As a matter of fact, you cast an unsigned int into a pointer on char...the issue is to be found on that line I guess. Dump the svc_args array.

Comment: define what you mean by service number how are you passing the service number?

Comment: @Heyji using cast on char* with negative int as index is the method used for SVC by many books/online sources.

Comment: @old_timer Number associated with the function that called SVC_Handler

Comment: right passed in the instruction or a register or what?  thats the question, in order to extract it how was it encoded, if you dont know that then that is your first problem, then once you know you can figure out why you dont see it

Comment: Or in other words, show how you are trying to invoke the service.

Comment: @elmulinho: I didn't know but I know C/C++ and I can tell it is not a good practice. Note this is not a cast on char * but a cast on an int into a char *...I Don't get the point.

Comment: @Heyji the point is to get data preceding that pointer which is itself is stored in an `int`. How else would you do it? Apart from `*((char*)svc_args[6]-2)` which means the same thing.

Comment: @Jester I will edit with the rest of the code and add some more info

Comment: _"compiler puts r0,r1,r2,r3,r12,r14, return address and xPSR in svc_args"_ - no it doesn't. Why would it? Your inline asm simply passes the stack pointer to the function. You should also make sure you know if you are in thumb or arm mode as the offset will be different.

Comment: Actually on armv7-m (which stm32 might be) the cpu itself saves those registers automatically.

Comment: It looks like you want `SVC_Handler` to be `__attribute__((naked))` since you use a `b` instruction inside inline asm to leave the function.  If you let GCC emit a function prologue, that could change things (especially in a debug build).  And if it inlines into its caller an optimized build, that's eve worse.  (Although that's not a concern if it's only called via hardware dispatch.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define svc(code) asm volatile ("SVC %[immediate]"::[immediate] "I" (code))
```

This creates the assembler of the form `svc #1`.  Note that the '1' is encoded in the instruction op-code.  In order to find the '1', you have to look at the `lr` and load the op-code at that address and then parse (by masking) the value.

For instance,

```
ldr r1,[lr]            ; load svc opcode to r1 (might need an offset)
and r1, r1, #SVC_MASK  ; may need shifts as well.
```

This is not efficient as you are treating a *code* pipe as *data*.  The normal way to do this is to define an service register, like `r7` and then set `r7` to the '#1' before the `svc #0` instruction.  So, the macro is something like,

```
#define svc(code) asm volatile ("mov r7, %[immediate]\n" \
                                " SVC #0"::[immediate] "I" (code) \
                                 : "r7" /*clobbers r7*)
```

You can use just `r0`, but if your call hierarchy gets more complex, many functions may put args in r0,r1,r2,r3 and then you will need to shuffle them.  That is why `r7` is typically used.

---

> why is `svc_number` equal to 248 whereas I was expecting 1

It looks like you thought it was put on the stack and this is **NOT** the case.  The value 248 is just something random on the stack.

Comment: Although I have seen a lot of examples with SV Calls for GNU GCC using the syntax I provided (one of which is in The Definitive guide to Cortex M4), the solution with using r7 as a holder for svc code worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I see [the recommendations here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s02s07.html), I think that the offset '6' might be different for your system depending on what happened in the exception table;  Unless `SVC_Handler` is the primary entry.  Basically your offset '6' is trying to get the `lr` and the look at an instruction back 2 bytes which should be the `SVC` number (I guess the low byte is the mask operation which assume endianess and is fine for a Cortex-M).